# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.serialization'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, torch

When I run a project used Pytorch I came up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train_drnet.py", line 10, in <module>
import utils
File "/home/muse/drnet-py/utils.py", line 18, in <module>
from data.kth import KTH 
File "/home/muse/drnet-py/data/kth.py", line 7, in <module>
from torch.utils.serialization import load_lua
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.serialization'
```

how to solve this,please?

Answer (score 2):

I think it was removed from Pytorch about a year ago, you can try tourch file instead - https://github.com/bshillingford/python-torchfile