# Problem importing module: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.checkpoint'

Tags: python, import, pytorch, google-colaboratory, fast-ai

I am following this [example](https://humboldt-wi.github.io/blog/research/information_systems_1819/group4_ulmfit/#ome) of ULMFiT. Here is the [github](https://github.com/MichaelSchimpke/SIS_ULMFiT).

I am running the model_forward_pass.ipynb in Google Colab. I am running the first code block which is this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import torch
!pip install fastai==0.7.0
!pip install torch
import fastai
from fastai.imports import *
from fastai.torch_imports import *
from fastai.core import *
from fastai.model import fit
from fastai.dataset import *

import torchtext
from torchtext import vocab, data
from torchtext.datasets import language_modeling

from fastai.rnn_reg import *
from fastai.rnn_train import *
from fastai.nlp import *
from fastai.lm_rnn import *
from fastai.text import *

import dill as pickle
!pip install spacy
!python -m spacy download en
import spacy
import html

import pickle
import collections
#!pip install nbimporter
import nbimporter
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bd3be060f151> in <module>()
      6 import fastai
      7 from fastai.imports import *
----> 8 from fastai.torch_imports import *
      9 from fastai.core import *
     10 from fastai.model import fit

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/fastai/torch_imports.py in <module>()
      1 import os
----> 2 import torch, torchvision, torchtext
      3 from torch import nn, cuda, backends, FloatTensor, LongTensor, optim
      4 import torch.nn.functional as F
      5 from torch.autograd import Variable

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 import warnings
      2 
----> 3 from torchvision import models
      4 from torchvision import datasets
      5 from torchvision import ops

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/__init__.py in <module>()
      4 from .squeezenet import *
      5 from .inception import *
----> 6 from .densenet import *
      7 from .googlenet import *
      8 from .mobilenet import *

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torchvision/models/densenet.py in <module>()
      3 import torch.nn as nn
      4 import torch.nn.functional as F
----> 5 import torch.utils.checkpoint as cp
      6 from collections import OrderedDict
      7 from .utils import load_state_dict_from_url

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch.utils.checkpoint'
```

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107156/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-torch-utils-serialization), but I am still not sure how to fix my problem.
What should I do to fix this?

Comment: Could you please mention what is the version of your pytorch installation?

Comment: The problem isn't in `pytorch`... the problem is within `fastai`. fastai 0.7.x installation issues [here](http://forums.fast.ai/t/fastai-v0-install-issues-thread/24652). fastai 1.0.x installation issues [here](http://forums.fast.ai/t/fastai-v1-install-issues-thread/24111).

Comment: @Anwarvic Do I have to follow the environment setup instructions if I am using Google Colab?

Comment: @Rish,  believe so